# General term for each inflected form of a lexeme

Tags: declension, conjugation, terminology, english

*illī* is a X of *ille* declension.
*illī* is singular dative masculine form of *ille*.

In  the first sentence what we should say instead of X?

Comment: If possible be specific; call it the dative. Otherwise, I think I'd go for 'endings.' After all the rhetorical ornament which uses the repeated sounds of inflexions, *homoioteleuton,* is just posh (id est: Greek) for 'similar ending.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply say: "*Illi* is an inflected form of *ille*. *Illi* is the singular dative masculine form of *ille*."
(I am not sure what the role of "declension" in your example is. I found it more natural to leave it out.)
In all generality, I would just use the expression "inflected form".
In a more specific case, you can consider "oblique case", but that only applies to case inflection.